# Flex order and flex-direction not work in IE11 and Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to use `flex order` or `flex-direction` on a `<td>` in a table, but it fails in IE11 and Edge. Could anyone tell me why or give me an other way to change their order? Here is the code snippet.

```css
tr {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /* flex-direction: row-reverse; */
}
td.a {
    order: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    -webkit-order: 2;

}
td.b {
    order: 1;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="a">1</td>
                <td class="b">2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: working alright in IE11 and Edge

Comment: @VXp I hope that it could be implemented by css

Comment: @kukkuz It will be "1 2" in IE11 or Edge, but I need "2 1"

Comment: Working fine in Edge, but not IE.

Comment: @VXp Really? It will not work in my Edge: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Comment: Yes, works fine in Microsoft Edge 41.16299.371.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299, which I guess is not the latest, strange.

Comment: Works on Microsoft Edge 41.16299.665.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299 also... Are you using a pre-release or "Insiders" version?

Comment: IE11 has a lot of bugs in flexbox (see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for some), which will likely not get fixed.

Comment: One of them is that `order` will not work on an element with `display: table-cell`, which is what a `td` has by default. If you change it to `display: block`, the order works. Not sure the point of using a table at that point though :).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have applied "display: block" to the <td>, <table> and <tbody>, but it still not works. And my Edge and IE11 are installed with the win10, strange :(